raspberry pi 4 model B won't booting anymore
i have an rpi4 that suddenly stop to boot. i flashed new time my card sd. the red LED lights up continuously, and the green LED blinks several times without stopping. i plugged the ethernet cable but this one don'

blinks several times - if there is a boot issue, the green LED blinks in a pattern of long/short blinks - this pattern can indicate what the issue is. i flashed new time my card sd what with? i.e. what OS did you flash and how did you flash it. Did you try a different SD card? Is your pi connected to a monitor, if so, what do you see. Have you tried booting from a USB thumb drive (you can flash it the same as an SD card)

In fact the green LED blinks in a pattern of long blinks which means that the rpi don't read the sd card, and i mean that i flashed my sd card many times where i formatted it and i flashed it each time with different raspbian and i tried a new sd card also but nothing new happens

a pattern of long blinks what is the pattern - there is no pattern that is JUST long blinks, so, what you describe is not happening - anyway, if the sd card reader is somehow broken, try booting from a USB thumb drive (or even a USB to SATA with SATA SSD - which is what all my pi 4's do)

ok thank you . i will try

you still haven't described the blink pattern ... is it 3? 4? 5? etc

i mean the green LED blinks many times without stopping what means that it is unable to read the sd card and when i i put the ethernet cable, the LEDs in the port didn't blink. i don't know what should i do with it. i want to know if the problem is in rpi itself

so, in the intervening 5 or so days, did you try booting from USB instead?

no i didn't because i haven't and i was in pressure because i need to continue my work. so i changed another rpi and the same problem happened now that's why

so you now have 2 Pi 4's doing exactly the same thing with exactly the same SD card? hmmm. You know what that strongly indicates

no with two different sd cards not the same one

What operating system are you flashing on to the sd card? and, as you said "I will try" to booting from usb 6 days ago, have you tried that yet?
